# django - production/development migrations and databases mixed up

Tags: python, django, database, debugging

This is my first Django app deployment, a lot to learn. So this is my settings for `DATABASES` in `settings.py`

```py
DEBUG = False

if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'db_name',
            'USER': 'db_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }
```

---

#### Problem:

1. For fixing a bug, I updated some fields in models locally, `git push`, and `git pull` on server, make migrations on server like I normally would locally; the migrations were successful, however, they don't seem to have applied

(if it's of any relevance, the bug fixing was some phone number field changed from `IntegerField` to `CharField`, preventing the error "Verify that this value is less than or equal to 2147483647"; But the weird thing is there wasn't any error for the cellphone `IntegerField` before deployment and running locally)

---

#### Confusion:

1. I remember that only one superuser was created on postgres database, or at least I thought it was, but I can log in with this superuser account in both production and development (that is no matter the `DEBUG` is set to `True` or `False`), how is that possible??
2. Same are the images uploaded only once, but can be viewed on the website no matter it's DEBUG or not

---

#### Assertion:

Does this mean that the code above in `settings.py` is fundamentally faulty? Only one `default` database can be set in django? Or I did something wrong with the migrations?

---

PS. I'm not familiar with DATABASE command at all, so any pointers on that to solve this problem is appreciated as well

---

### Solution, for some who has the same problem:

Try @ruddra 's answer below as well as restarting the django app:

```sh
$ sudo service gunicorn restart
```

maybe you are using `apache2` or some other than `gunicorn`, restarting somehow helped the correct database or changes in the code to apply as well.

Comment: How is `DEBUG` being set?

Comment: As usual `DEBUG = True/False` at the beginning of the file, more ways to set this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than this approach, I would suggest to use [**`ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) to distinguish how to load database. For example:

```
# command line
export USE_PROD_DB=true

# in settings.py

DEBUG = False

if not os.environ.get('USE_PROD_DB', None):
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'db_name',
            'USER': 'db_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 2 quick questions: 1. 'true' doesn't have to be capitalized? 2. what's the benefit of using Environment variables?

Comment: 1. it does not make any difference, because when you use `os.environ.get()` you will get a string, rather than a boolean value, you can consider using django environ instead to parse boolean value directly from environment variable. 2. Well, you can simply google it, this is the first result from my search: https://hyperlane.co/blog/the-benefits-of-environment-variables-and-how-to-use-them where a nice explanation has been given.